# How to get your Android app in search results

Tags: android, google-play

I recently published a password generator app on the Android market called Mega Pass.  But the only way people can find it in search results is if they search for Mega Pass or my developer/publisher name.  Is there any way that I can get my app to appear under searches like password generator or password protection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Description of your app, just add the Keywords you want like password generator,password protection.

Comment: Is there any way to make the app show up near the top of the results, or do you need to pay to do that?  Right now my app is about the 100th result when I search password generator.

Comment: If it is possible try to change the name of the app. bcoz no one will search with the name mega pass.